# Edit the PHP curl/libcurl Configuration

Tags: php, curl, libcurl

How do I edit the PHP curl configuration? I have PHP 7.1.0 and curl 7.51.0 set up on Windows 10 with Apache. For example, if I want to enable NTLMWB, it is currently set to "No".

Correct me if I'm wrong, but we are talking about libcurl since it is part of PHP and not the command line version.

My research has led to me believe that these settings are in "ext\php_curl.dll" and I would have to compile my own PHP to change these settings.

I have been able to compile PHP with Visual Studio C++ 2017 RC, but I used the configure lines, for PHP 5.3.x Thread Safe, from [How to build a release for Windows](https://wiki.php.net/internals/windows/release). The build did not create a php_curl.dll and I did not attempt to run it.

Am I on the right track or is there a much easier way to edit these configuration settings?

Current curl configuration.
[image]

Comment: My set up is on Linux but there is a curl section in the php.ini file.  My NTLMWB is also set to "yes" by default...

Comment: @ivanivan The php.ini was the first place I looked. I searched the entire php package for NTLMWB and php_curl.dll was the only place it showed up.